# Is it sufficient to provide a privacy policy only in english language?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, language

Regarding GDPR, is it sufficient for a gaming app available in some commercial app store to provide a privacy policy only in english language?

Is a translation necessary for every country of the EU where the app is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one strives to have a privacy policy in the language in which the app is offered. The goal is for your users to be able to read the legal docs in the same language as the rest of the offering. That makes sense. 
I've also come across opinions that advocated to potentially offer up the privacy policy in the language of your own region, so your relevant data protection authority/authorities in general could read them.

Example: your app is English, Spanish, you are based in Germany. So you'd offer English, Spanish and German.

Personally, I very much tend to the opinion: offer the legal docs in language that your gaming app is running in.